# Can't connect jenkins to a remote git repository

Tags: git, jenkins, remote-server, ssh-keys

I am trying to connect my jenkins to a remote git repo such as `aa-bb-server`

In the credentials configuration, I put the user name and the private key, this is what I get:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h aa-bb-server HEAD" returned status code 128:
stderr: fatal: 'aa-bb-server' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Changing the Jenkins user to `root` didn't work.

Locally I can ssh to the repo, clone, etc.

Comment: What is the exact value you have set for the **Repository URL** in your project's git configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please follow the below step 
if you installed jenkins in your server please initialize the git empty repository --> `git init`

Then go to github --> click on **profile dropdown** --> **settings** --> **devloper settings** --> **personal access token** --> **generate new token** --> **select all scopes** --> **copy the token**

Then go to Jenkins --> **manage Jenkins** --> **github settings** --> **add user** --> **Select secret text ** --> **paste the token**

> And test your git hub access
>   after that go to project and add your repository URL (which is ends with .git)

Comment: Actually I fixed simply by putting the public key under the jenkins .ssh folder inside his directory in /var, changed the owner to jenkins, granted jenkins with root privileges, made sure the repo name is correct along the branch and it worked.  Thank you for the help!